# CKAN translations not updating

Tags: translation, ckan

Working with CKAN version 2.9.8 and trying to update language translation file in English to change default CKAN labels following: https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/i18n.html

No error messages when compiling po file to generate mo file. However, interface labels are not being updated. Some months ago I managed to update the labels without any problem following the steps listed in the link above.

Tested this across different languages with the same outcome.  I went to the point of replacing the target Enligh mo file by another mo file from a working foreign language. However, again there was no label update.

Any suggestions on how to identify the source of the problem and/or fix it?